# Sed Remove 3 last digits from string

Tags: sed

```
27211;18:05:03479;20161025;0;0;0;0;10991;0;10991;000;0;0;000;1000000;0;0;000;0;0;0;82
```

Second string after `;` is time. `gg:mm:sssss:`. I just want to be `gg:mm:ss:`

Like so:

```
27211;18:05:03;20161025;0;0;0;0;10991;0;10991;000;0;0;000;1000000;0;0;000;0;0;0;82
```

I tried with `cut` but it deletes everything after n'th occurance of character, and for now I am stuck, please help.

Comment: you can use `cut` if number of characters in 1st column is fixed.. for ex: `cut -c1-14,18- file`

Comment: Are there always 5 digits in the seconds field, or can there be fewer?

Comment: @Charlie, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this one liner a try:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" 'sub(/...$/,"",$2)+1' file
```

It removes the last 3 chars from column 2.

#### update with sed one liner

If you are a fan of sed:

```
sed -r 's/(;[^;]*)...;/\1;/' file
```

Comment: Works great! Thank You!, but im not familiar with awk yet, is there any solution to do this with sed? or cut?
Or just please give simple explanation of this awk line?

Comment: @CharlieBondurant, it is setting input and output field separator as `;`, deleting last three characters of second field `$2` and then printing the modified line... it has some idiomatic awk ways like `+1` after the `sub` which will take a while to get used to.. it is equivalent to `awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/...$/,"",$2); print $0}'`

Comment: @CharlieBondurant added sed one-liner

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^;]+;[^;]+)...;/\1;/' file
```

(Or)

```
sed -r 's/^([^;]+;[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})...;/\1;/' file
```

Comment: since format in 2nd column is known, we can also use `sed -E 's/^([^;]+;.{8}).../\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

It also can be something like `sed 's/(.*)([0-9]{2}\:){2}([0-9]{3})[0-9]*\;(.*)/\1\2\3\4/g'`

It is not very clean, but at least is more clear for me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl for this:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=:\d\d)\d+(?=;)//' file
```

That removes any digits between "colon-digit-digit" and the semicolon (first match only, not globally in the line).

If you want to edit the file in-place: `perl -i -pe ...`

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -E 's/(:[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3}/\1/' file
```

or perl:

```
perl -pe's/:\d\d\B\K...//' file
```